# checking array of id and value against database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is how the `$conversationArray` array look like,

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(0)
  }
```

Now I have to check against a table if any of the conversation id has timestamp more than what's given. If yes I need the affected conversation_id.

I'm not sure how to take **id** and **timestamp** from `$conversationArray` array to fit into this query.

```
 $query = '   
  SELECT conversation_id FROM tbl_notification    
  WHERE timestamp IN >implode(',', $timestamp),   
  AND conversation_id IN >implode(',', $id)  
  ';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is get the `IDs` and `Timestamps` in separate array and perform `implode()` on each.

To get the separate array you can use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) which returns the values from a single column from the input array.

So to get the IDs and Timestamps in single array you would do something like this,

```
$ids = array_column($mainarray, 'id');
$timestamps = array_column($mainarray, 'timestamp');
```

Now you can perform **implode()** on each of them to query the database.

> Consider using Prepared statements for SQL queries to avoid SQL
>   injection attacks.

Comment: ,I got my code right by your suggestion, however it doesn't permit me to use comparison operator with IN like: WHERE timestamp > IN(

Comment: `IN` is not used with comparison operator.

Comment: but i need to check if timestamp in db is greater than the one in array..what's the possible way?

Comment: For that put multiple `OR` conditions for each value of the array.